# Deleting dynamic input fields in Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Noob question but I can get fields to render in Vue but not sure how to delete my fields. I added an index option in the `v-for` directives but not sure what to do after that. Thanks!

Here is a working JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/xu55npkn/

```
<body>

<div id="app"></div>

<script>

const createNewOption = () => { 
    return {
    text: '',
    isAnswer: false
  }
}

const createNewQuestion = () => {
  return {
    text: '',
    options: [createNewOption()]
  }
}

  var vm = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    template: `<div class="quiz-builder container">
<div v-for="question in questions">
  <div class="input-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" v-model="question.text" placeholder="Enter a question">
    <span class="input-group-btn">
      <button class="btn btn-danger" type="button">X</button>
    </span>
    <span class="input-group-btn">
      <button class="btn btn-secondary" type="button" @click="addOption(question)">Add an option</button>
    </span>
  </div>
  </br>
  <div class="input-group" v-for="(option, index) in question.options" style="margin-bottom: 20px">
    <span class="input-group-addon">
      <input type="checkbox" v-model="option.isAnswer">
    </span>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" v-model="option.text" placeholder="Enter an option">
    <span class="input-group-btn">
      <button class="btn btn-danger" type="button">X</button>
    </span>
  </div></br>
</div>
<button class="btn btn-default" @click="addQuestion" :disabled="questions.length >= 5 ? true : false">
  Add another question
</button>
<button class="btn btn-primary" style="background-color: #ffcc00; border: #ffcc00">
  Create quiz
</button>
</div>`,
    data () {
    return {
      questions: [createNewQuestion()],
      showQuestions: false,
    }
  },
  methods: {
    addQuestion () {
        this.questions.push(createNewQuestion())
    },
    removeQuestion (index) {
       this.questions.shift(index)
    },
    addOption (question) {
        question.options.push(createNewOption())
    }
  }
})

</script>
```

Comment: The short answer is that you need to remove the question from your questions array.  How you want to handle that is up to you.  You might want to remove just the last question, or you might want to remove by index.

Comment: Ok. I've updated JSFiddle and question. I can remove a question easy no problem. It's removing individual options on those questions that is giving me trouble.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your updated question, you have already solved for removing questions, although yev's answer is a much better way for removing questions.

To remove options, you need to add a new handler for `removeOption` that takes in both the question (which you are iterating over) and the option (which you are iterating over.  Vue handles both of these scenarios for you.  You can then find the index of the option and splice the array.  See this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1a7o3zny/).

template:

```
<button class="btn btn-danger" type="button" @click="removeOption(question, option)">
    X
</button>
```

component:

```
removeOption (question, option) {
    var index = question.options.indexOf(option);
    if (index > -1) {
        question.options.splice(index, 1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your delete button should look like:

```
<div v-for="(question, i) in questions">
  <div>
    <input v-model="question.text">
    <span>
      <button @click=removeQuestion(i)>X</button>
    </span>
    <span>
      <button @click="addOption(question)">Add an option</button>
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Notice I've added `i` (index) in your for loop and click handler for X button.

Your remove function will look like:

```
removeQuestion (index) {
  this.questions.splice(index, 1);
}
```

`Array.shift` will remove only first item in the array which is not exactly what you want :)

Comment: Ah. Thanks! Much better.